# Identification of 2-pin connector on 1999 Pump Machine

Tags: connector, identification, pins

During my master thesis, I need to install an old vacuum pump to an machine (1999).

However I encountered this type of connector, which I am not familiar with. I have searched around the web with no results. Due to the weight and placement of the pump in a cleanroom, replacing this connector with another is a last resort.

I would be really glad if you could help me identify this type of connector.
The diameter of these pins is approximately 1.5mm while I measured a length of 7.5mm.

The width of the inside is 11mm while the height is 6mm.

Thank you for your help!

[image: photo of connector]

Comment: Looks like two bare pins in custom enclosure. Measure them and find some matching socket pins.

Comment: Can you post another picture? The pins aren't in focus, and I can't tell if they are flared or straight...

Comment: Start searching but don't hold your breath.
https://www.digikey.com/en/resources/connectors/index

Comment: your fingers are in focus .... unless you are asking a question about your fingers, post another picture?

Comment: could be XT90 perhaps?

Comment: connector doesn't look very clean.  maybe I don't understand cleanrooms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a Souriau connector [SMS2P1](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/souriau/SMS2P1/SOU1217-ND/1243172)  (Note that is the part number for the housing the [pins](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/contacts-multi-purpose/336?k=&pkeyword=&sv=0&pv233=1&sf=0&FV=ffe00150%2Cz1812.4.1243172&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25) are seperate).

[image]